# Why QWORD seems to use 12 byte memory

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64

I am new to assembly language, and looking at GCC's unoptimized code-gen for a function that initializes `int`, `long`, and `char` variables.

```
int main()
{
    int intVariable {};
    long longVariable {};
    char charVariable{};

    return 0;
}
```

[you can check the code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c7Khne5vP)

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-17], 0
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

- I create an *integer* and it takes 4 bytes [rbp-4]  :  **0 -> 4**
- Create a *long* seems to use 12 bytes [rbp-16] **4 -> 16**
- Create a *char* takes 1 byte [rbp-17] : **16 -> 17**

Can somebody explain me why long data type seems to use 12 byte?

Comment: What you are seeing is padding for alignment.  `long` for you it 8 bytes wide so it needs 8 byte alignment.

Comment: but in that time 4 byte for `int` [rbp-4] 8 byte `alignment` [rbp-12] and 8 byte `long` it should be [rbp-20] ?  @NathanOliver

Comment: 20 isn't a multiple of 8.

Comment: rdp to rdp-4 is for the `int`.  rdp-5 to rdp-8 is padding.  rdp-9 to rdp-16 is for the `long`

Comment: @Jester 17 is not a multiple of 8 too when we use `byte`

Comment: @NathanOliver than why there is not any padding between `long` and `byte`

Comment: @Jester when i add another integer it started from 24. I understand what you mean.

Comment: @NathanOliver so here is what i understood because of ram memory is created from 8 bytes even if first `int` is 4 byte it has too use 8 byte space that 4 byte is padding, than long is using `9 to 16` and `byte` is using 17-24

Comment: Fun fact: if you reorder the declarations in the source, un-optimized GCC packs them better, squeezing in the char into `[rbp-5]`, with the int and long at the same places: https://godbolt.org/z/1Po6WTWc1  If you enable optimization (and use `volatile` so they still exist), GCC will pack them for you regardless of source order, using 13 bytes of the red-zone: https://godbolt.org/z/1aqr7P3PT

Comment: Sure 17 isn't a multiple of 8, but you are only storing a byte there which requires 1 byte of alignment (so none) not 8.

Comment: @PeterCordes so if there was a 3 byte type it should use 4 to 7,  after 8 byte it can not. That is what i understood from the behaviour when using an `int` and a `byte`

Comment: Sure, try it yourself with `char arr[3] = {0}` which has alignof(arr) = 1, or `struct { short a; char b; } var;` which has alignof(var) = 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes actually i don't understand the last comment.

Comment: I mean add those local variable definitions to the source on Godbolt and look at how the asm changes.  See where GCC puts them.  Without optimization it might just lay out the variables in source order, or it might fill gaps.  Although we can see from your `char` variable that it put it last, not filling the gap unless optimization is enabled.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah i understand that. I am new to c++ too, but i will find out. Thank you.

Comment: New to C++ and noticing the dark magic that some people don't notice for years. I salute you.

Comment: This must be red zone since there's no subtraction of `rsp`. The weird thing is, what would have happened if this function called another? Would the local variables get clobbered, or would they have been placed in different offsets entirely?

Comment: @puppydrum64: The red zone is only used in leaf functions, for exactly that reason.  So if this function contained a call to another, the variables might well have ended up at exactly the same locations relative to rbp, but you'd see something like `sub rsp, 24` included in the prologue so that the locals are above rsp.  Obviously it is not acceptable for the compiler to generate code that results in local variables randomly being clobbered, since that isn't what the C language specifies to have happen, unless it can prove that observable behavior remains conformant.